# List of numbers is invalid output for CSV in jq

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I need to get a list of amazon images created by the company. This will go into a variable that I will put into csv format and output to a spread sheet.

I need to account for the image id and the size of the volumes attached to it.

If I try this command:

```
cat ab-prod-images.json |  jq -r '.Images[] | [.ImageId, ([.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize])] | @csv'
```

This is the error I get:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:53471): array ([100,5,10,2...) is not valid in a csv row
```

I'm storing the output of that command in a variable, that I'll use to output to a spread sheet.

What I want is for a comma separated list of volume sizes to appear in the same cell in the spread sheet.

This is an example of the json that I'm using:

```
{
"Images": [
    {
        "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
        "Description": "TRAN05-12-13-2018",
        "Hypervisor": "xen",
        "ImageId": "ami-000bd263d51e443f2",
        "State": "available",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-0f1076dce3103833f",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 100,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdi",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-0c7d71a9d3887a048",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 5,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdg",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-00402196b9e023a72",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 10,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdk",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-05f65a62735de2846",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 20,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdj",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-0d350170b9d5c62bb",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 40,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdh",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-04679d09d89609e79",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 30,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdf",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-0b5f861fd93da6b20",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 5,
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "Architecture": "x86_64",
        "ImageLocation": "155775729998/AB-P-RIDD-TRAN05-12-13-2018",
        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "OwnerId": "123456789101",
        "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
        "CreationDate": "2018-12-14T01:39:31.000Z",
        "Public": false,
        "ImageType": "machine",
        "Name": "TRAN05-12-13-2018"
    }
]
```

}

Here is the full and complete json that I'm trying to use: [FULL JSON](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/fe8bc9bbfae7293b054b6b01d455c015)

How can I get the list of VolumeSizes to go into the same cell in the spread sheet I'm creating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@csv`'s input must be a flat array, but your filter (`.Images[] | [.ImageId, ([.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize])]`) produces a nested array because you put volume sizes into a subarray (**[**`.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize`**]**):

```
$ jq -rc '.Images[] | [.ImageId, ([.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize])]' file.json 
["ami-000bd263d51e443f2",[100,5,10,20,40,30,5]]
```

So, use following command instead.

```
jq -r '.Images[] | [ .ImageId, .BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize ] | @csv' ab-prod-images.json
```

which yields:

```
"ami-000bd263d51e443f2",100,5,10,20,40,30,5
```